# Write the Value in a image2D

Tags: r, graph

Is it possible to write the value in R in a image2D plot?

Some of the values are too close to eachother. Therefore I'm not able to use the "legend" at the side. I would like to write the numeric value additional to the colorkey in the position.

In the following picture is an example of what I mean.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513531/heatmap-with-values-and-some-additional-features-in-r
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290364/heatmap-with-values-ggplot2

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not aware about a `image2D` plot, but as stated, you can use `ggplot2` to get the desired output: is it `image2D` compulsory? If not, if you share some data (if you can), posting the result of `dput(your_data)`, it's going to be easier to find a solution.

Comment: @bbiasi Thank you. This looks like a good solution

Comment: @s_t Thank you for the suggestion. I don't have to use `image2D`. I'm gonna try it with `ggplot2` like in the links from @bbiasi