# Heat map with additional values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap

I created a heat map for sample data. I would like to add some information about the average for each hour and the sum for each day of the week. It is best to have an additional column on the right and an additional row at the top of the chart, without filling.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
TD=data.frame(wday=rep(c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
                         "Saturday"),24), hour=rep(0:23, each=7), N=sample(100:300, 168))

ggplot(TD, aes(hour, wday,  fill=N)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "white", na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_bw() + theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 23)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(N)), size=4) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 23, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution for me is to include these means in your dataframe and then plot your heatmap afterwards.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("viridis")

TD=data.frame(wday=rep(c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
              "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"),24),
              hour=rep(0:23, each=7), 
              N=sample(100:300, 168))

df <- TD %>% group_by(wday) %>% summarise(N=round(mean(N)), hour="avg") %>% rbind(TD)
df <- TD %>% group_by(hour) %>% summarise(N=round(mean(N)), wday="avg") %>% rbind(df)

df$wday <- factor(df$wday, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                  "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "avg"))
df$hour <- factor(df$hour, levels=c(as.character(0:23), "avg"))

ggplot(df, aes(hour, wday, fill=N)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white", na.rm=TRUE) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 23)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(N)), size=4) + 
  coord_fixed(xlim=c(0, 25), ratio=1)
```

[image]

**EDIT :** without filling in for the new elements.

```
df <- TD %>% group_by(hour) %>% summarise(N=round(mean(N)), wday="avg") %>% rbind(TD)
df <- df %>% group_by(wday) %>% summarise(N=round(sum(N)), hour="sum") %>% rbind(df)

df$wday <- factor(df$wday, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "avg"))
df$hour <- factor(df$hour, levels=c(as.character(0:23), "sum"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(colour="white", data=subset(df, hour!="sum" & wday!="avg"), 
            aes(hour, wday, fill=N)) +
  geom_text(aes(hour, wday, label=N), data=df, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(df$hour)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=levels(df$wday)) +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_fixed(xlim=c(0, 25), ratio=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make average values without filling in?

Comment: Do you mean filling colors into tiles by 'filling in'?

Comment: Yes, I prefer without fill in avg.

Comment: not right off the top of my head now. I'm not sure if that is possible within `geom_tile()`.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513531/heatmap-with-values-and-some-additional-features-in-r/49516914) is the similar case.

Comment: Oh, that's neat. Thanks for sharing that. I will look into that later and edit if possible.