# Create a heatmaps with average values on the very right column and bottom row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a heat map, where average values are depicted on the very right column and in the bottom row. I found a question that is very similar to mine -
[heatmap with values and some additional features in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513531/heatmap-with-values-and-some-additional-features-in-r)

Everything works well, however, I do not need highlighted cells for average values. Could you help me to unhighlight cells with average values?

```
library(ggplot2)
q1<-structure(list(hour = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), E = c(-15.6, 
-17.2, -13, -11.6, -9.8, -13.2, -16.8, -15.8, -13.8, -12.8, -26.4, 
-42.2, -40.8, -38, -41.2, -48.2, -47.2, -42.4, -18.4, -35.4, 
-47.2, -42, -26.6, -24.8), K = c(-15.8, -23, -22.4, -15.8, -15.6, 
-18.5, -21.4, -24.4, -18.8, -15.4, -46.8, -53.4, -43.6, -42.4, 
-48.6, -48, -57, -19.2, -14.8, -23.2, -39.2, -43.8, -28, -13), 
    L = c(-20.6, -19.8, -12.6, -7.4, -11, -23.8, -25.2, -21.4, 
    -20.4, -20.2, -17.6, -18, -20.2, -30.4, -22.6, -25.8, -31.8, 
    -35.6, -43, -37, -36.8, -44, -47.4, -33.2), N = c(-15.4, 
    -28.6, -16.6, -15.6, -18.4, -20.2, -25, -22.8, -14.2, -10.8, 
    -31.4, -37.6, -37.2, -32, -37.4, -40.4, -40.4, -23, -8.6, 
    -11, -23.2, -33, -26.2, -8.2), P = c(-17, -16.8, -22.6, -15.8, 
    -15, -23, -23.8, -21.8, -17.4, -17.4, -21.2, -18.2, -11, 
    -14.6, -26.6, -31, -27.4, -29.4, -27.4, -29.6, -33, -34.8, 
    -16, -17.4), R = c(-7, -22.4, -20, -12, -15.4, -18.8, -22.6, 
    -20.4, -10.2, -4.4, -21.2, -28, -30.6, -29.4, -26, -22.8, 
    -31.4, -20.4, -4.8, -18.6, -27.2, -35, -48.8, -32.6), T = c(-19.4, 
    -21.2, -16.2, -16.6, -16.8, -16.2, -21.8, -23.4, -13, -13, 
    -36.2, -42.2, -41, -38.4, -39.6, -47, -43.2, -42.4, -21.8, 
    -23.8, -40.2, -34.6, -23.8, -15), Average = c(-15.8285714285714, 
    -21.2857142857143, -17.6285714285714, -13.5428571428571, 
    -14.5714285714286, -19.1, -22.3714285714286, -21.4285714285714, 
    -15.4, -13.4285714285714, -28.6857142857143, -34.2285714285714, 
    -32.0571428571429, -32.1714285714286, -34.5714285714286, 
    -37.6, -39.7714285714286, -30.3428571428571, -19.8285714285714, 
    -25.5142857142857, -35.2571428571429, -38.1714285714286, 
    -30.9714285714286, -20.6)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

q1$Average<-rowMeans(q1[,2:8])

dat2 <- stack(q1[-1])
dat2$hour <- q1$hour
dat2$ind <- factor(dat2$ind, levels=c("E","T","K","N","R","L","P", "Average"))

ggplot(mapping = aes(ind, hour)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = values), subset(dat2, hour != "Average" & ind != "Sum")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(values, 1)), dat2) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("Average", 24:1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("E","T","K","N","R","L","P", "Average"), position = "top") +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis() +
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of an `ifelse` to replace the values mapped on fill to `NA` for your average column and row like so. The value to be used for the `NA` value could then be set via the `na.value` argument of `scale_fill_xxx` where I chose `NA` or `transparent`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(ind, hour)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = ifelse(!(ind == "Average" | hour == 1), values, NA)), subset(dat2, hour != "Average" & ind != "Sum")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(values, 1)), dat2) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("Average", 24:1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("E","T","K","N","R","L","P", "Average"), position = "top") +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(na.value = NA) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(fill = "values")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try barplots instead of numbers.

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
row_ha = rowAnnotation(Average = anno_barplot(q1$Average,axis_param = list(direction = "reverse")))
column_ha = HeatmapAnnotation(Average = anno_barplot(colMeans(q1[,2:8])))
ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(as.matrix(q1[,-c(1, ncol(q1))]), right_annotation = row_ha, top_annotation = column_ha, col = viridis::viridis(10))
```

[image]

Or points with regression line and boxplots showing medians instead of means

```
row_ha = rowAnnotation(Average = anno_lines(q1$Average,axis_param = list(direction = "reverse"), smooth =T))
column_ha = HeatmapAnnotation(summary = anno_boxplot(as.matrix(q1[,-c(1, ncol(q1))])))
```

[image]

Without clustering on row and columns

```
Heatmap(name = "value", as.matrix(q1[,-c(1, ncol(q1))]), right_annotation = row_ha, top_annotation = column_ha, 
        col = viridis::viridis(10),cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F)
```

There are a couple of R-packages availabel for [heatmaps](https://www.biostars.org/p/205417/). Thus, you can try the `superheat` package as well.

```
library(superheat)
superheat(as.matrix(q1[,-c(1, ncol(q1))]),
          yr = q1$Average,
          yr.plot.type = "scattersmooth",
          yr.axis.name = "Average",
          yt = colMeans(q1[,2:8]),
          yt.plot.type = "bar",
          yt.axis.name = "Average")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful. Do you know how to preserve the order in y-axis (factor(dat2$ind, levels=c("E","T","K","N","R","L","P")))?

Comment: @PriitMets Set `cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F` to avoid clustering with dendrograms. See my edit